# Direct Access support for IoT Enterprise

Tags: windows, direct-access

The company where I work has a set of kiosk devices which we install at remote sites. For the new version of these devices, we are looking at running Windows IoT Enterprise as the OS.

With this change, our existing MDM solution is not supported. When exploring alternative options, we came across Microsoft's Direct Access solution, which satisfies all of our requirements as far as management and cost effectiveness.

While Direct Access seems to be the solution we're looking for, there is one make-or-break question that I have not been able to find an answer to: `Is the Direct Access client supported on Windows IoT Enterprise`?

For the sake of clarity, by "supported" I mean "if it breaks, can we call Microsoft Support?" If it runs on the IoT client but is not a supported solution, we will need to look elsewhere.

Thank you

Comment: For Windows IoT Enterprise, what is supported is enumerated in your licensing agreement. Contact your OEM for further information.

Comment: If you do not have DirectAccess now, it should not be considered an option. Microsoft recommends not using it for new implementations. That said, I don't see anything about DirectAccess on the IoT Connectivity page.